# stopping a rotating mass to achieve linear velocity

Tags: angular-momentum, velocity, space

So I've been thinking about space, and I had this idea. I haven't found any prior art online for it, and from my limited understanding it seems like a viable idea. So I guess my question is, what am I missing? or is this truly a good new idea?

Here goes the idea:

Assume a out-of-balance system where an object (M) is connected to a motor at a pivot point (p), which is fixed to a payload (L). Once the object is rotating with tangential velocity V, suddenly halting that rotation by applying a break will transfer the angular momentum into linear momentum in the direction of the tangent.

```
-       -M->
/|    /  |  \
L|=======p   |
/|    \     /
-       ---
```

The important point is that the centrifugal force for the object while it's rotating is actually much smaller than the force created by the break being applied. An obvious side effect would be a vibration created, but from my calculation the force created by stopping the rotation is an order of magnitude larger than the force created by the vibration.

Not to mention that the vibration will happen equally in all directions, while breaking the rotation will produce a very linear force.

So, what am I missing? Or is this really viable?

P.S.: From my calculations, this system would not generate enough lift on earth, so it really would only be useful in space.

Comment: Could you add a sketch of the setup?

Comment: "Assume a out-of-balance system where an object of a mass M is connected to a pivot point with a distance r (for the radius) from the pivot point" so the pivot point has a distance of $r$ from the pivot point?

Comment: Did some edits to make it more clear.

Comment: And some other edits for more clarification...

Comment: The combined center of mass is going to remain fixed, so the payload COM is going to oscillate back and forth as well as counter-rotate. So alignment is going to really tricky.

Comment: But my question is: am I correct in assuming that applying a break in the motor to stop the rotation will generate a linear movement by transferring the inertia of the rotating mass to the system as a whole?

Answer (score 3):

You are referring to what is called a [centrifugal machine](http://www.wired.com/2010/11/the-physics-of-punkin-chunkin/) at the punkin' chunkin' event, although you've got the operation wrong. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1calSPjoR4) is a video showing how it's done. Where you've gone wrong is in thinking that launch occurs when the arm is abruptly stopped. Rather, with this sort of device you simply let the projectile go at the proper moment, then slow down the arm gradually.

And the idea is totally worthless for space use, since you are making an invalid assumption: "an object (M) is connected to a pivot point (p)". Sorry, no unmoving pivot points in space. In space, not only can no one hear you scream, there's no place to plant your feet. So rotation would have to be applied to a pivot point at some intermediate point on the arm, with the product of arm lengths and counterweight masses being equal. That is, for a projectile mass m and an arm length l, and a counterweight mass M and arm length L, $$m\times L = M\times l $$ Worse, when you let go of m and it heads on out at some velocity v, at the same time the counterweight will be launched in the opposite direction at a velocity V, where $$ V = (\frac{m}{M})v $$  In other words, at any instant the momentum of each mass is of equal magnitude but opposite direction, and when you let one go the other will also try to take off. Prior to launch the tension in the connecting rod/cable kept the two together, but that obviously doesn't apply afterwards.

Comment: Just to clarify, the point where m x L = M x l will be the center of mass of the arm.

Comment: I was assuming an electric motor in the center driving the rotation as well as breaking it. And the whole thing attached to a payload, so the pivot point would be fixed on relation to the payload.

Comment: Also, you seemed to assume a counter weight, when I specifically said this would be off balance, with only one object attached to the pivot point, causing vibration one rotating but causing a bigger acceleration when stopped.

Comment: I reworded the question a bit to clarify. Also made the ascii-art sketch more precise by including the fact that the pivot point is fixed to a payload.

Comment: @DanielRuoso - Also, you seemed to assume a counter weight, when I specifically said this would be off balance" Yes you did. And as I pointed out, in outer space there's no place to plant your feet.

Comment: Doesn't attaching the entire thing to a payload make a difference? Please see the revised ascii-art diagram...

Comment: @DanielRuoso - connecting the apparatus to a heavy payload helps, but only quantitatively. Upon operation, the mass goes one way at high speed, and the payload goes the other way, but more slowly. And using the revised ASCII will provide massive vibration to the payload.

Comment: Right, but my original question is: will stopping the rotation by applying a break actually cause linear movement as I am assuming, or am I missing something more fundamental?

Comment: And additionally, is my initial calculation correct in predicting that the forced caused by applying the break will be an order of magnitude bigger than the force on the vibration?

Comment: Also, it seems you're assuming the system will let go of the rotating mass, when what I am proposing is that the rotation will stop, but the mass will remain attached, so the break would transfer the entire tangential inertia of the rotating mass to a forward movement. Or at least that is my assumption that I am not sure is correct...

Answer (score 2):

I think this would happen. The rotating rod, would have a counter rotating reaction on the payload. As a result you won't be able to aim very well.

[image: animation]

Comment: If that is the only problem, then I could simply add a second motor rotating the other way, I could still stop the rotation when both masses are moving to the outside, does that mean that it would cause a forward movement?